# Rails 4 Nested Form Showing UP in Edit, but not in Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, bootstrap-modal

I am having a form that I use for the edit screen, that I also populate on another screen as Modal (when a user just signed up). However, there is a little error with the Nested Form Display on that Modal only. I have been trying to find it for hours. Here is my code:

```
= form_for @user do |user|
```

.form-group
    %label{:for => :first_name}
      First Name
    = user.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control"

```
%label{:for => :middle_name}
  Middle Name
= user.text_field :middle_name, class: "form-control"

%label{:for => :last_name}
  Last Name
= user.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control"

%label{:for => :image}
  Profile Picture
= image_tag @user.image.url(:thumb),  class: "img-circle" if @user.image.exists?
= user.file_field :image, class: "form-control"

%label{:for => :headline}
  Headline
= user.text_field :headline, class: "form-control"

%label{:for => :bio}
  What are you currently Involved with? (Hint Just copy your LinkedIn Highlight)
= user.text_area :bio, class: "form-control user_text_area"

%label{:for => :twitter}
  Your Twitter Handle
= user.text_field :twitter, class: "form-control"


%label{:for => :school}
  School
= collection_select(:user, :school_id, School.all, :id, :name,  {prompt: true, :required => ""}, {  class: "filter-option pull-left form-control" } )

%br/

%label{:for => :course}
Course
= user.fields_for :course_user do |cu|
  = cu.select :course_id, Course.all.map { |c| [c.name_with_intake, c.id] }, {}, class: 'filter-option pull-left form-control', id: 'courses_select'
-# = collection_select(:course, :course_id, Course.all, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Course"}, {:id => 'courses_select', class: "filter-option pull-left form-control"})
```

Then my User Modal does Show this:

```
has_one :course_user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_user
```

The field that I am stuck with is the "Course field" to add a course to a User. Now, here is the thing, Others have suggested to remove the user part, so the code would be:

```
%label{:for => :course}
Course
= fields_for :course_user do |cu|
  = cu.select :course_id, Course.all.map { |c| [c.name_with_intake, c.id] },
```

Or change the :course_user into CourseUser.new

```
%label{:for => :course}
Course
= fields_for CourseUser.new do |cu|
  = cu.select :course_id, Course.all.map { |c| [c.name_with_intake, c.id] },
```

Both result in the field showing in the modal. However, both also prevent the data from being saved. So I am wondering...what is going wrong? I appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

After a long night figuring this out and eventually calling a help-line, I figured out what the problem was. The User Controller#edit had a line that I completely overlooked that made it work. So you will need to have user.fields_for. If need be, I can help you with a similar issue.

```
= user.fields_for :course_user do |cu|
```

This is the code that worked in the end. I have some steps to be taken:

1 - Look in the server logs, see what Params are parsed. Check the params

2 - Again in the server logs, see what items get pushed

3 - Then check what actions are in the Controller and if you have added

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_user
```

to the respective Model (change :course_user)